# Plotting plant female and male sex phase durations

Tags: arrays, r, excel, graph, plot

I am having troubles trying to figure out how *one would create a line graph with individual plants on the Y axis and on the X axis* a continuous line segmented into the plants respective opening, sex phase, and wilt dates.

I have roughly 60 individual plants - each with anywhere from 5-15 flowers - and their respective opening dates, the date they entered male phase, the date they entered female phase, and the subsequent wilting date for the individual flowers.

Here is the data I have so far: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lhz8z0qo4sla5w/Dphase.txt?dl=0

Here is a crude drawing of the graph I'm trying to create (the values I graphed are arbitrary):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qd1ela0093dvoq/2015-10-15%2013.29.55.jpg?dl=0

PID = name of the plant

Gender= (m/f -> male/female) the gender of the plant when measurements were taken (Note that opening is included in the Gender row m, although it didn't enter male phase until the date specified under 'sex'. Similarly in the f row, the date specifies under 'sex' corresponds to when it left male phase and entered female phase)

Opening = the date when a plants flower opened

Sex = the date when the flower entered its respective sex phase Wilt = the date the individual flower wilted

Flower = the relative flower position within the plant

Hopefully my links have worked. If anyone could give me a hand in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A quick tutorial via example: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/exploring_w_graphics.htm

Comment: It took some time before I understood that this shouldn't be moved to gardening.stackexchange.com. :-)

Comment: I'd use three lines in a survival curve. However, If you want some more help, why not [include some data, and what you have tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It  would be easy for us to help you if you provide us some data to play with!

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry about that, I am new at using this site so I still have some things to learn :). I have uploaded the data I am using.

Comment: Can you hand sketch what the output would look like for a few of the PIDs? For example, say the dataset only consisted of PIDs 115, 82, and 69, what would the graph look like?

Comment: Here is a zoom in of my crude drawing :)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/69b5mbusv7o2flm/2015-10-15%2013.30.03.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Finally, I'd like to create an array of the total number of flowers within each plant in their respective male and female phase durations, like so:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ylywvstzr22gdf/2015-10-15%2013.30.15.jpg?dl=0

^enhance:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ztduj49blz8hls/2015-10-15%2013.30.24.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @jeremycg would you care to elaborate on how one would use three lines in a survival curve?

Comment: @RyanTaylor: You should pay more attention to the rest of jeremycg's comment.

Comment: @BondedDust which part are you directing my attention towards?

Comment: Read his comment again. He made two points: one that you commented on, and one that you have so far ignored. Where's the code?